# Find profit in percentage

Tags: percentages

if person smith buy one book in 180 rupees (RS) after few day they sell this book in 250 rupees then who much smith gain profit(profit in percentage) after selling the book.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Profit = Selling Price - Cost Price = 250-180 Rs = 70 Rs . Now percentage profit = profit /Cost Price X 100 = (70/180).100 = 38.88%